# WPF - Raise property changed for ToString

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tostring, telerik-grid

Currently i have the problem, that my business object overrides `ToString` for delivering data to some telerik control (`RadListBox`/`RadListBoxItem`). The model which overrides `ToString` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged.` Is it possible in c# to raise the method `ToString` to be changed? The initial values get's displayed well, but later changes will be ignored. For example:

```
public class ViewModel : UI.MVC.ViewModelBase
{
    private string name;

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name ?? "--";
    }
}
```

For example if `Name` is chagned, `ToString` should be called to get the new value.

**EDIT**

The `ViewModel` from above is embedded in another viewmodel. which is binded to a `RadPropertyGrid`:

```
public class FirstViewModel :  : UI.MVC.ViewModelBase
{
    public FirstViewModel()
    {
        SelectedItem = new ViewModel();
    }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

An instance of RistViewModel is the datacontext of the containing window.

**XAML**

```
<telerik:RadPropertyGrid NestedPropertiesVisibility="Visible" 
    x:Name="propertyGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsGrouped="True" 
    Item="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you binding to ToString() in the first place?

Comment: You could try `RaisePropertyChanged(null)` which would indictate that all properties on the object have changed. It might prompt Telerik to re-evaluate.

Comment: @kyriacos_k that is the default behaviour of the most wpf controls, if not `DisplayMemberPath` is set.

Comment: Ah I was thinking you were binding directly to `Name`

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer passing `null` did not work. But thank you :)

Comment: Posting your XAML would probably help

Comment: I hove not so much html. I use the telerik `RadPropertyGrid` with nested properties. The "header" property of the controls binds automatically `ToString`. The `RadPropertyGrid` generates it's member on it's own, so you woun't see so much in the xam. But i will add it :)

Comment: Try this: add some event to `ViewModel`, add handler to it in  `FirstViewModel` where you call `PropertyChanged("SelectedItem");` on `FirstViewModel`. This should work for xaml you provided in question.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible in c# to raise the method ToString to be changed?

No, it is not possible. You cannot force other code to call `ToString()` again as a direct consequence of some other event. For that matter, the only reason `INotifyPropertyChanged` works is that, by convention, code knows to subscribe to that event and call a property getter (which is a type of method) when the event is raised. The event doesn't actually force any code to call the property getter; it's just that anyone who bothered to subscribe to the event is almost certainly going to call that method when the event is raised.

Of course, you can always set up whatever mechanism between consenting pieces of code you want. But for code that itself has no reason to believe that it might get a different result from `ToString()` depending on when it's called, such a mechanism won't exist.

> For example if Name is chagned, ToString should be called to get the new value.

You can always subscribe to `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` yourself, and then do something to force the `ToString()` method to be called again. It is not clear from the little code you provided how this might be done; maybe setting `SelectedItem` to `null` and then back to the desired object.

All that said, while I'm not familiar with the control you are using (`RadPropertyGrid`), assuming it follows the normal WPF model, then if it is in fact displaying the `SelectedItem` object in some way, I would guess that it's doing so in a manner that would be compatible with the use of a `DataTemplate` for that type. I.e. if you were to declare a `DataTemplate` for the `ViewModel` class, you could bind directly to the `Name` property. For example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="l:ViewModel">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

…and WPF would automatically update the displayed name if and when it changes.

Your `ToString()` method provides a default name value of `"--"`. This could be incorporated into the `Name` property itself if you want, or you could add a new property, e.g. `DisplayName` that provides that (i.e. if for some reason you need `Name` to remain `null` when the property hasn't been set).

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're doing, it's impossible to know for sure what the best approach would be. But it would be surprising for a *good* WPF library to not support normal binding and templating mechanisms, and instead to rely completely on a `ToString()` override without any mechanism for value update notifications.